# get No module named urls while rendering template in celery task

Tags: python, django

The site works ok, but when a celery task is called which renderes template for EmailMultiAlternatives, I get `ImportError: No module named urls`.
If I comment out just one app in settings.py (modal_announcements), it works. The app itself runs ok in the site. This is the urls.py (which could not be found, thoght it apparently exists):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from mezzanine.conf import settings
from modal_announcements.views import announcement

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url("^announcement/(?P<pk>.*)%s$" % ("/" if settings.APPEND_SLASH else ""), announcement,
                           name='announcement')
                       )
```

here are the project's urls:

```
if settings.USE_MODELTRANSLATION:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url('^i18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.set_language', name='set_language'),
        url(r'^robots\.txt$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='robots.txt',
                                               content_type='text/plain')),

        url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
    )

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns("",
                       url("^$", home, name='home'),
                       url(r'^inliner$',
                           inliner, name='inliner'),
                        url(r'^autocomplete/', include('autocomplete_light.urls')),
                       ("^orders/",
                        include("orders.urls", namespace="orders")),
                       ("^shop/",
                        include("shop.urls", namespace="shop")),
                       ("^programs/",
                        include("programs.urls", namespace="programs")),
                       ("^prices/",
                        include("prices.urls", namespace="prices")),
                       ("^tour/", include("tour.urls", namespace="tour")),
                       ("^misc/", include("misc.urls", namespace="misc")),
                       **("^announcements/", include("modal_announcements.urls", namespace="announcements")),**
                       ("^%s/" %
                        settings.EVENT_SLUG, include("mezzanine_agenda.urls")),
                       # ``mezzanine.urls``.
                       ("^", include("mezzanine.urls")),

                       )


urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
)
# Adds ``STATIC_URL`` to the context of error pages, so that error
# pages can use JS, CSS and images.
handler404 = "mezzanine.core.views.page_not_found"
handler500 = "mezzanine.core.views.server_error"

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    )
```

traceback:

```
[2017-10-22 01:43:47,493: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: send_mail_template_task[abb16580-9037-4bd9-9f5c-75f85e6a51b4]  
[2017-10-22 01:43:47,576: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task send_mail_template_task[abb16580-9037-4bd9-9f5c-75f85e6a51b4] raised unexpected: ImportError('No module named urls',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andy/.virtualenvs/stable/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 374, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/andy/.virtualenvs/stable/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 629, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/andy/stable/inte-production/misc/tasks.py", line 14, in send_mail_template_task
    headers=None)
  File "/home/andy/stable/inte-production/misc/utils.py", line 277, in send_mail_template
    msg.attach_alternative(t.render(context),"text/html")
  File "/home/andy/.virtualenvs/stable/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 74, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/andy/.virtualenvs/stable/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 210, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/andy/.virtualenvs/stable/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 202, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/andy/.virtualenvs/stable/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/home/andy/.virtualenvs/stable/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/home/andy/.virtualenvs/stable/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 493, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/home/andy/.virtualenvs/stable/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 578, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/andy/.virtualenvs/stable/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 432, in _reverse_with_prefix
    self._populate()
  File "/home/andy/.virtualenvs/stable/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 284, in _populate
    for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
  File "/home/andy/.virtualenvs/stable/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 401, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/andy/.virtualenvs/stable/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 395, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/andy/stable/inte-production/inte/urls.py", line 273, in <module>
    ("^announcements/", include("modal_announcements.urls", namespace="announcements")),
  File "/home/andy/.virtualenvs/stable/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 33, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named urls
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the error:
I installed modal_announcements module Looong ago; since I wanted to modify it, I then copied the code to my project and adopted it as needed; it did not give me errors.
But after installing celery it somehow picked the old modal_announcement's urls (or views, or whatever...) from .virtualenv instead of my project and exposed the error to me in this tricky way. Took me ages to figure out!
Morale: clear up properly!